# Difficulty calculating blood oxygen saturation

Tags: c#

I'm sorry if this is not an appropriate question for the programming exchange.

I am having trouble with a function that is intended to calculate the saturation of oxygen in blood.  I'm trying to use well known functions and science, but the result is coming back as a negative value who's absolute value is a few percent off the correct value.

```
private float _calculate_blood_oxygen_saturation(
    float inspiredPartialPressure_kPa,
    float arterialPartialPressure_kPa,
    float temperature_C
)
{
    // Constants for the oxygen-hemoglobin dissociation curve coefficients
    const float _A = -173.4292f;
    const float _B = 248.3763f;
    const float _C = 0.7102f;
    const float _D = -0.9959f;
    const float _E = -0.2337f;

    // Calculate the oxygen saturation curve coefficient
    float temperature_K = temperature_C + 273.15f;

    float oxygenSaturationCurveCoefficient =
        _A +
        ( _B / temperature_K ) +
        ( _C * Mathf.Log( temperature_K ) ) +
        ( _D * Mathf.Pow( 10.0f, _E * ( temperature_K - 50 ) ) );

    // Calculate the oxygen saturation percentage
    float saturationPercentage = ( inspiredPartialPressure_kPa / arterialPartialPressure_kPa ) * 100.0f;
    float saturation           = ( saturationPercentage / oxygenSaturationCurveCoefficient ) * 100.0f;

    return saturation;
}
```

The value should be a positive value between 0 and 100, but is returning as a negative value.  I feel like something wrong with either my calculation of the oxygen coefficient, or the constants I'm using.

Edit:

The inputs are:

- `arterialPartialPressure` is a constant (95 mmHg * 0.133322f)
- `temperatures` will be near 20C
- `inspiredPartialPressure` will always be around 20

Added info: A link to the description of how to "calculating blood oxygen saturation":

> Oxygen saturation is the percent of hemoglobin present as
> oxyhemoglobin; it is measured directly with oximetry. Oxygen capacity
> is the maximal amount of oxygen that can be bound to hemoglobin. This
> value is calculated by multiplying the patient's hemoglobin by 1.34
> and is expressed in milliliters per 100 milliliters.

(source: [https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/oxygen-saturation#:~:text=Oxygen%20saturation%20is%20the,milliliters%20per%20100%20milliliters](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/oxygen-saturation#:%7E:text=Oxygen%20saturation%20is%20the,milliliters%20per%20100%20milliliters). )

Edit -- Following up, based on information in sources provided above, I've revised my formulae and calculations, taking some liberties with average physiology constants to create a reasonable facsimile with viable outputs.

Here is the updated code.

```
private float _calculate_blood_oxygen_content(
    float inspiredPartialPressure, 
    float arterialPartialPressure) {

    // Calculate the partial pressure of oxygen in arterial blood via alveolar gas
    // using the formula PaO2 = PIO2 - (PaCO2 / R) - (F * (P - PaH2O))
    // Note: we are intentionally disregarding:
    //      F: the fraction of inspired gas which is not oxygen
    //      PaH2O: and the partial pressure of water vapor in the inspired gas

    float PaCO2 = 5.25f; // partial pressure of CO2 in alveolar gas, in kPa 
                         // (widely variable, but distilled to an average until 
                         // a working model to correctly calculate this is built)

    float R = 0.8f; // respiratory exchange ratio (overly simplified)

    float PaO2 = inspiredPartialPressure - (PaCO2 / R);

    // Calculate the oxygen-hemoglobin dissociation curve,
    // using the formula S = (1 / (1 + 10^((p50 - log(P)) / n))) ^ m

    const float p50 = 3.5463652f; // kPa
    const float n = 2.25f;
    const float m = 2.5f;

    float x = 1f + Mathf.Pow(10f, (p50 - Mathf.Log(arterialPartialPressure)));
    float S = Mathf.Pow(1f / x / n, m);

    // Calculate oxygen content of bound and dissolved oxygen,
    // using the formula CaO2 = (SaO2 x Hb x 1.34) + (PaO2 x 0.003)

    const float oxygenSolubility = 0.003f;
    const float Hb = 14f;  // average hemoglobin concentration in g/dL
    float SaO2 = S * 100f;

    float CaO2 = (SaO2 * Hb * 1.34f) + (PaO2 * oxygenSolubility);  // mL O2 / dL blood

    return CaO2;
}
```

Comment: What are the input values for `inspiredPartialPressure_kPa`, `arterialPartialPressure_kPa` and `temperature_C`?

Comment: Protip: Instead of using `float` types with unit-names as variable suffices (e.g. `_kPa`), instead consider using `struct`-based _refinement-types_ to represent _values-with-units_, this helps prevent unintentional unit/dimension errors from happening (this is related to _dimensional analysis_ in software).

Comment: What is `Mathf`? .NET only has `System.Math`.

Comment: `UnityEngine.Mathf` is a wrapper for `System.Math` that abstracts explicit conversions from `double` to `float`

Comment: I ran your code at my end and your `oxygenSaturationCurveCoefficient` is negative because your `_A` value (`-173.4`) is dwarfing the other values you're adding together. I know _absolutely nothing_ about oxygen-hemoglobin dissociation curves,  but your program code looks otherwise correct, so I suspect your problem is that you converted the mathematical formulae to C# incorrectly, in which case we cannot help you because we don't know what the formulas are.

Comment: Well, I appreciate it, in any case.  I have high confidence that the constants are correct, but much lower confidence in my implementation of the formula.  I'll head over to the biology exchange to see what they have to say over there.

At least I can be confident that the C# code is sound enough.  

I have to admit, I'm not sure what my next step should be?  Should I delete my question?  Mark it as answered.  Apologies, I'm new here.

Comment: Leave the question open for now - and once you post it to Biology.SE please post the link to it here, I'd like to see what they say too, for my own personal interest.

Comment: You may consider reviewing [C# data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types). Also see [Floating-point numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types). Please add the formulas to the OP, as well as, sample data - input and expected output (ie: results).

Comment: What is the formula you intended to implement? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Why are you multiplying a percentage by 100? float saturation           = ( saturationPercentage / oxygenSaturationCurveCoefficient ) * 100.0f;

Comment: Do you have any reference on that formula and used constants? the "few percent off the correct value" might be a result of missing precision with the `float` datatype (I'd suggest `double` instead) But maybe you got a sign or parenthesis wrong somewhere ... But we can't help you with that unless we see, what the formula is acutally supposed to be ...

Comment: The following may be of interest: [A mathematical model of the hemoglobin-oxygen dissociation curve of human blood and of the oxygen partial pressure as a function of temperature](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6478594/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either there is something wrong with your formula or your constants. Taking the inputs from your question, `oxygenSaturationCurveCoefficient` will always be negative because in

```
float oxygenSaturationCurveCoefficient =
    _A +   // (a)
    ( _B / temperature_K ) +  // (b)
    ( _C * Mathf.Log( temperature_K ) ) +  // (c)
    ( _D * Mathf.Pow( 10.0f, _E * ( temperature_K - 50 ) ) );  // (d)
```

(all values below are somewhat rounded, but that doesn't really matter)

- in (a) `_A` has a value of `-173`
- in (b) `_B / temperatureK` will be something like `248/290` (given your input `temperature_C` is about 20), thus something like `0.85`
- in (c) `_C * log(290)` will be something like `0.7 * 2.4`, thus about `1.9`
- in (d) `_D * pow(10, E * ...)` will be `-0.99 * pow(10, -0.2 * 240)`, thus `-0.99 * pow(10, -50)` ie practially `0`

So if you calculate everything like written here you have

```
-173 + 0.85 + 1.9 - 0 = ~-170
```

Ie the only relevant factor in this calcuation is the constant `_A`, all other values here are more or less negligible. Especially the last line makes me wonder, if there is some error in the formula (for instance the parenthesis at the wrong location) because `pow(10, -50)` is `0.0000000.....00001` so in fact irrelevant for the result

All following calcuations are only dividing or multiplying by positive numbers, so cannot change the sign anymore.

Acutually, I don't know anything about that topic. But just doing the math with the values and the formula you provided, I cannot see any possiblity that the final `saturation` can get positive

Comment: I need to go back to the drawing board.  I am fairly certain that my interpretation of formulas and constants is off and needs to be re-evaluated.  This is the accepted answer, roughly translated to "check your formula", which is what I will do.
Much thanks!